# Global NTLM authentication on linux for different applications

Tags: linux, centos, proxy, squid, ntlm

I'm currently attempting to use various open-source programs under centos to connect through an ISA proxy server that requires NTLM authentication.
In an attempt to solve the authentication needs and since some of the tools don't have ntlm authentication features built-in (though all of the tools we need have a way of connecting through a proxy without authentication), I have thought about installing some other software layer that would "proxy/tunnel" the applications to perform the authentication on the NTLM ISA.

I've attempted to install Squid in hope it could handle the NTLM authentication in the following setup:

multiple applications <---> squid <--NTLM AUTH--> ISA <---->  WWW

However I can't seem to get squid to automatically authenticate to the ISA...

What options are there for this kind of problem (we need to authenticate and pass multiple apps through a proxy that requires NTLM authentication )?

Answer (score 1):

[cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) and [ntlmaps](http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/) are HTTP proxy servers which do NTLM authentication to an upstream proxy.